# how to take an integer input in main function and make an array of that size in any class?

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

For example,

```
class Quota{
    private:
        int t_quota, intake, ID[];
        float percentage[];
};
```

This is the class i want to modify. And here is the main function from which i will be passing an integer value to set the size of two arrays in the class Quota.

```
int main(){
    int intake;

    cout<<"Enter the total number of students who took the test this session of 2015, September: ";
    cin>>intake;
    Quota qr(intake);
}
```

The thing i'm trying to do here is make the size of the two arrays viz. `ID[]` and `percentage[]` 'intake'. As in, `ID[intake]`, `percentage[intake]`.
    Can it be done? I guess so but i tried via constructor but didnt get it right. Anybody knows how this can be done?

Comment: This just hit me. How about we make a global variable and store the input there?

Comment: Use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: The comment recommending  `std::vector` contains a link to a reference site for it. There are also many examples on how to use it if you just do some quick searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create an array of the fixed size which is unknown at the compilation time.
This means you need to allocate array of the required size in the constructor and then release it in the destructor.

But I would recommend to use `std::vector` for such purpose.

```
class Quota{
    Quota(const int size): ID(size), percentage(size)
    {
    }

    private:
        int t_quota, intake;
        std::vector<int> ID;
        std::vector<float> percentage;
};
```

Comment: How do i assign the value of 'size'  variable? The normal way?

Comment: Quota q(size, id, per);
is this the right way to pass the parameters to the above constructor?

Comment: @SubhamKharel Just like you wrote in your question: `Quota qr(intake);`

Comment: @SubhamKharel The constructor receives only one parameter (assuming that all the vectors should have the same size). If you need support different sizes then change the constructor to: `Quota(const int size1, const int size2): ID(size1), percentage(size2)`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, we should avoid to using low level data structure in c++, such as `array`. You should use `vector<int> ID, vector<float> percentage`, instead of `ID[], percentage[]`. Then you can set size of `ID and percentage` in `Qouta`'s constructor. For example:

```
Quota::Quota(const int& intake)
{
    ID.resize(5); //set ID's size
    percentage.resize(5);
}
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Arrays are not something to be avoided, bad advice. Dynamically allocated arrays on the other hand...

Comment: @CoffeeandCode, you can use `std::array`, not `int ID[]`. Is it ok?  BTW, `c++ primer` have said it clearly.

Comment: I know you *can*, but just because you can doesn't mean you have to or it is better practice.

Comment: Also, your rule really only applies to beginners. I use low-level constructs often and have no way around it. Otherwise, how would I implement something such as `std::array` or `std::vector`?

Answer (score 0):

When you are determining the size of the array in run-time, you cannot initialize it in compile-time.

May be you can try allocating it first and then assigning a pointer.
This will work. But I am not sure if it would fit your requirement.

```
class Quota{
public :
    Quota(int size);
    int *  allocate_ID(int size);
private:
    int t_quota, intake;
    int * ID;
    float percentage[];
 };

 Quota::Quota(int size)
 {
     ID = allocate_ID(size);
 }

 int * Quota::allocate_ID(int size)
 {
     int * ID_arr = new int[size];
     return ID_arr;
 }

int main(){
     int intake;

     cout<<"Enter the total number of students who took the test this session of 2015, September: ";
     cin>>intake;
     Quota qr(intake);
 }
```